# Where is `gapplication`?

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I have installed Gnome 3.12 on Ubuntu 14.04 using the gnome-team/staging PPA.

Launching gnome-document using the application launcher (.desktop) works fine, but if I type `gnome-document` in a terminal, it complains about gapplication not being found.

Indeed, after some googling, I found that gapplication is here to launch apps using dbus. It seems also to be part of glib.

What package (if any) provides `/usr/bin/gapplication`? Is it possible to install it (possibly from source) on Ubuntu 14.04?

It would also be nice to learn more about this new way to launch apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/g/glib2.0/glib2.0_2.40.0-3/changelog) for the `glib2.0` source package, the `/usr/bin/gapplication` program was recently added to the [libglib2.0-bin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libglib2.0-bin) [image: Install libglib2.0-bin] package beginning with version 2.40.0-3.

This version of the package is not available for 14.04 but *is* now available in the 14.10 development release. So if you want to try the `gapplication` program, you can either upgrade to the 14.10 development version, wait for Ubuntu 14.10 to be released, or try backporting the glib2.0 packages yourself. The glib2.0 packages are not currently part of the gnome3-staging PPA.